# SmartGit RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 500

Tags: git, gitlab, smartgit

I am very new to this Git repository and not really understand how it works as it is said to be crucial for code management. Then got a friend recommend me to use SmartGit for starters like me. Currently I have created a website project for my reference and use SmartGit to store my code in GitLab.

Right now I have 1 repository with 2 local branch (master & and the other one I name it 'child'). I created the 'child' branch because the remote repository (GitLab)'s master branch is protected which prevented me to push my code and I do not see any options to change that branch status in GitLab.

Image of my repository: [My Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAKMM.jpg)

So I created the 'child' branch. I have succeed commit push the files, and in the next day, I tried to commit & push some new changes, then that error comes out:-

***The remote end hung up unexpectedly |
RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 500***

The Commit Error:[The SmartGit's Commit Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQN4k.jpg)

I have tried the `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` on SmartGit's git-cmd.exe but the error still comes around.

I have searched all over the internet and most of them mainly stated to use that command. But majority on the internet, the error is not the same as my 'HTTP code = 500'. So I have to create this question specifically to resolve this error. I hope this is regarded as good question and will be helpful to everyone in the future.....

Comment: How large is your repo?

Comment: @mwm314 is this what you mean? (http://i.stack.imgur.com/x2DIJ.jpg) . If you mean my project files then, all of them is 84.9MB

Answer (score 3):

An HTTP 500 error indicates an error happened on the server. Increasing the http buffer won't change a server-caused issue.

As the server is saying it's erroring out, you should contact your hoster to ask what's wrong. If you are hosting this yourself, check the logs of your hosting software to see what its log say that went wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I've contacted the server owner. There is no problem with pushing small files or individual files. The conflicts occurs with the large pushes. He said that, there is a problem with the reverse proxy and still working on the solutions. Right now, he give me the direct link with 8080 port and the pushes work fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have your server full. Check folders like /tmp. Normally it is at 100% of its capacity.